# Scala: Call a method as part of the constructor

Tags: scala, constructor, default-constructor

I have a class in Scala with two argument for its constructor:

```
class SomeClass (x:Int, y:Int) {
}
```

I need to expand the constructor so when an object of this class is initialized, some method is called, which uses the value of `x` defined in the primary constructor defaulted by Scala, and then outputs a value `z`:

```
def defineInputs(): Int = {
    val z = x + 1
    z
}
```

I want the value of `z` to be accessible publicly to all methods in the class, just like `x` and `y` are.

Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: What you mean by "loading a method"?

Comment: Maybe 'call' is a better term. Modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply define a `val` inside the class, like so:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class SomeClass(x: Int, y: Int) {
  val z = x + 1
}

new SomeClass(0, 0).z

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class SomeClass
res0: Int = 1
```

You could also use a case class:

```
scala> case class SomeClass(x: Int, y: Int) {
     |   val z = x + 1
     | }
defined class SomeClass

scala> SomeClass(0, 0).z
res0: Int = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Can it be done in the class itself since [http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html] mentions that "It only makes sense to define case classes if pattern matching is used to decompose data structures".

Comment: I disagree with that statement, but yes, it can be done! See my updated answer for more information. The reason I used a `case class` in my example is that the Scala compiler automatically generates the `apply` method (and the `unapply` method, too)  which eliminates the need to use the `new` keyword when constructing a new instance of the class.